# C# Visual Studio running program without debugger (ctrl+F5)

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2012

So I have this sample using one of my company dll.

```
    namespace LoggingSample
    {

    internal static class Log
    {
        private static ILogger s_log = LoggerRegistry.CreateLogger("ManagedLoggingSample");

        static internal ILogger Logger
        {
            get { return s_log; }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ILogProvider logProvider = new Logging.Provider.Log4netProvider("logging.config.xml") as ILogProvider;
            LoggerConfig.registerLogInterface(logProvider);

            Console.WriteLine("Initializing logging");

            Log.Logger.message(SEVERITY.LOG_DEBUG, "Debug message 1");

            // Add more logs
            Log.Logger.message(SEVERITY.LOG_INFO, "Log info Message {0} {1}", 2, "I am an error logged message");
            Log.Logger.debug("Debug Message 2");
            Log.Logger.error("Error Log message {0} {1}", 4, "i am an error message");

            Console.WriteLine("Done");
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");

            Console.ReadKey();            
        }
    }
 }
```

My problem is that on the console the messages are showing in Debug and Release only running without the debugger.

[image]

The program also outputs the text on a file but without the debugger the files is empty;
Anyone know what could be the problem here? could be a matter of settings?

The .xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
  <log4net>
  <root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="ColoredConsoleAppender" />
  </root>
  <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="ManagedLoggingSample.log" />
    <appendToFile value="false" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <maximumFileSize value="2KB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%-5p %d %5rms %-22.22c{1} %-18.18M - %m%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
      <appender name="ColoredConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ColoredConsoleAppender">
          <mapping>
              <level value="ERROR" />
              <foreColor value="White" />
              <backColor value="Red, HighIntensity" />
          </mapping>
          <mapping>
              <level value="DEBUG" />
              <backColor value="Green" />
          </mapping>
          <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
              <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
          </layout>
      </appender>
  <logger name="ManagedLoggingSample" >
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
  </logger>

</log4net>
```

I forgot to mention that only in Release without the debugger it doesn't show anything on the console and the log file is empty, the .exe from debug works just fine.

Comment: Can you post your logging.config.xml?

Comment: Hi @jacob, I attached the .xml file

Answer (score 0):

For the internal static class Log I provided an empty static constructor ( `static Log() { }` ). I think is a question of optimization, because the class is static, it was created before the call, now because we have a constructor
it knows to create the Log when it is called. If anybody has another answer, I'll gladly hear it.